# Compare power towers

Tags: tetration, big-numbers, power-towers, number-comparison

> Prove or disprove:
>   $3^{3^{3^{3^{3...^3}}}}$ with 100 threes $>4^{4^{4^{4^{4...^4}}}}$ with 99 fours.

Taking logs is useless, and there seems to be no other way to compare. Thanks!

Comment: My intuition says the $3$s are larger, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Comment: @DonThousand You are right, $3\uparrow \uparrow 100>4\uparrow \uparrow 99$ holds, which can be proven by induction ($3 \uparrow \uparrow (n+1)>4\uparrow \uparrow n$ holds for every postive integer $n$)

Comment: Additionally of interest would be to describe in some way HOW much larger it is. Is it more than a googleplex larger? More than twice as large? More than a googleplex times as large? No, none of these is even remotely close!

Comment: What does $\uparrow$ mean?

Comment: [Tetration notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to see that $3^3>6\times4$ and that

$$3^{6n}>6\times4^n$$

for all $n\ge1$. By induction this gives us:

$$3\uparrow\uparrow(n+1)>6(4\uparrow\uparrow n)$$

for all $n\ge1$.

Of course much better bounds can be given, but this suffices.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer for its brevity and tidiness. (+1)